# MySQL query to select companies due an invoice within 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display a list of companies from a table, who are due a new invoice to be sent within 30 days, but the problem I have is that when I create their new invoice, they remain on the list and I would like them to be removed.

`sw_practices contains` the company info

`sw_invoices contains` their respective invoice data

My current query is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SW_PRACTICES    AS  P
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            SW_INVOICES
    )AS I
ON
    P.PRAC_ID   =   I.PRAC_ID
WHERE
    P.ACTIVE    =   '2'
AND I.NEXT_DUE  >   NOW()   -   INTERVAL    7   DAY
AND I.NEXT_DUE  <   NOW()   +   INTERVAL    30  DAY
ORDER BY
    I.INV_ID    ASC
```

So this is successfully showing all due within 30 days which is correct.

Desired results is for it to show that invoice 01 is due within 30 days which is what it is doing, but when I create invoice 02 and the Next_due cell is a date 12 months in the future, I would like it not to show invoice 01 is due any more because that Prac_ID has an updated row with a newer invoice.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: No problem, have just approved an edit although i've never seen a query written like that so that's just confusing me now...

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Not sure why the GROUP BY is invalid? There is a grouping column, Prac_ID is in both tables to identify what company the invoice relates to etc..

Comment: OK i've taken GROUP BY off because I tried it without and it gave me the same results so it may not be required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted by adding a `WHERE Inv_ID IN (SELECT MAX...` in the sub-query, full query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM sw_practices as p 
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sw_invoices 
    WHERE Inv_ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(Inv_ID) 
        FROM sw_invoices 
        GROUP BY Prac_ID
    )
) as i 
ON p.Prac_ID = i.Prac_ID 
WHERE p.Active = '2' 
AND i.Next_due > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
AND i.Next_due < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
ORDER BY i.Inv_ID ASC
```